# NextJS - Static json data in Components?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am starting with NextJS.

I have a bunch of Json file that allows me to customize how to site looks. Those are static and fully known at build-time.

The information contains in those files are needed to render `Components` and do not need to be known by `Pages`.

I tried to use `getStaticProps` inside the `Components` but it doesn't seem to work.

(( I don't need a full CMS system, just those few json files ))

Can someone enlighten me, please :)
Thank you !

Comment: Are the JSON files within your Next.js app? Can't you just import them in the components that need it? Can you provide a code example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I would like to load those local static json files when the components need the extra configurations. How can I do this ? I can't use `fs` and `path` client side and for optimization, I want to do it at build time.